# Add data into multi-dimentional array with javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

```
[File 
    { size=295816, type="image/jpeg", name="img_new3.JPG"}, 
 File { size=43457, type="image/jpeg", name="nature.jpg"}
]
```

this is the data that i received from the script now i have to send only size and the name of the file with to the php file through ajax.
here is my code

```
            var files = []; 
            files["file"] = [];

            // file is an object that has the above result
            for( var i=0, j=file.length; i<j; i++ ){
                console.log( file[i].name );
                files["file"][i] = file[i].name;
                files["file"][i] = file[i].size;
            }

            // Send Request to Create ZIP File
            console.log(files)
```

i want to access the params for my PHP file:

```
file(
    name=>array(
          0=>"name", 
          1=>"size"
    ), 
    size=>array(...)
)
```

how do i make an array that send the data to PHP file like the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to use the [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) notation, not [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), and then you can pass it to your PHP function via [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

```
var files = {};
files["file"] = [];

// file is an object that has the above result
for (var i = 0, j = file.length; i < j; i++ ){
    console.log(file[i].name);
    files["file"][i] = file[i].name;
}
```

And then use that array with `JSON.stringify` to pass data to your PHP script like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "your url",
    type: "POST", //can be get also, depends on request
    cache: false, //do you want it to be cached or not?
    data: {files: JSON.stringify(files)},
    success: function(data) {
        //do something with returned data
    }
});
```

Anyway I suggest you changing the way you store your data. Objects are very useful in this case:

```
var files = [];

// file is an object that has the above result
for (var i = 0, j = file.length; i < j; i++ ){
    console.log(file[i].name);
    files.push({
        name: file[i].name //you can add all the keys you want
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have js array ready so just use the [jQuery post method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) to send the created array to the php file which then processes the array the way you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

Your multidimensional array can be JSON encoded and sent as a string via ajax to the PHP script, which can decode the JSON back to an array/object:

```
// assuming the array is in files var
$.ajax({
    url : 'page.php',
    type : 'POST',
    data : { myFiles : JSON.stringify(files) },
    success : function(response){
        console.log("successfull");
    }
});
```

On the PHP side:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    $filesArray = json_decode($_POST['myFiles']);
    print_r($filesArray);
}
```